# How to pass a variable from AJAX response to a JS function onclick

Tags: javascript

I want to pass the value of a variable to a javascript function as parameter on click of a link.I get this value from AJAX response. For this i have done this code but getting error in console that test not define.

```
var test = data.fileName;

alert('Hello world ' + test); // this gives me Hello world download/15__Priority____4x6__Label.JPEG
var lbDownHtml = '';
lbDownHtml += "<div><a href='" + data.functpath + "' ><span>Download Label</span></a>";
lbDownHtml += "</div>";
lbDownHtml += "<div><a id='print_Link' onclick='print_funct(test);return false;'><span>Print Label</span></a>";
lbDownHtml += "</div>";

function print_funct (test) {
    alert('Hello world '+test);
}
```

How can I pass my variable test to my function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code considers test as a string, Make it a variable assignment like below.

```
lbDownHtml += "<div><a id='print_Link' onclick='print_funct(" + test + ");return false;'><span>Print Label</span></a></div>;"
```

This will put what ever value test holds into the function call.

**EDIT:** on your request , when test should be a string

```
lbDownHtml += "<div><a href='" + data.functpath + "' ><span>Download Label</span></a>";
lbDownHtml += "</div>";
lbDownHtml += "<div><a id='print_Link' onclick='print_funct(\"" + test + "\");return false;'><span>Print Label</span></a>";
lbDownHtml += "</div>";
```

Comment: iam getting this error after i replaced my code with urs "SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list" P.S the link is unclickable.

Comment: now em getting this "expected expression, got end of script"

Comment: SyntaxError: missing ; before statement now this error in console

Comment: I have edited code in my question thats how its there

Comment: I edited my answer again and also tested it, This must work for sure. Sorry for troubling you so many times

Comment: Can u please edit my question whole code not just this line but over so that i can paste and check ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104379/discussion-between-ammar-ul-hassan-and-reddy).

Answer (score 3):

You need to concatenate the `test` variable with the string:

```
lbDownHtml += '<div><a id="print_Link" onclick="print_funct(' + test + ');return false;"><span>Print Label</span></a></div>';
```

Comment: iam getting this error after i replaced my code with urs "SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list" P.S the link is unclickable.

Comment: Pls check my edited question em getting "expected expression, got end of script" in console